# loading dump.json file to a new postgres database from django

Tags: json, django, postgresql, django-database, django-deployment

I'm switching from the default sqlite3 database to the PostgreSQL database  but I'm getting an
**DETAIL:  Key (slug)=(superadmin) already exists.** error

the steps i did:

> py manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --natural-primary -e contenttypes -e auth.permission -e sessions --indent 4 > db.json

> python manage.py flush

> change database settings to postgres

> py manage.py migrate

> python manage.py load data dump.json

now I have an empty sqlite3 database and i cant load the data to my Postgres database :(